# What does "loud" mean in terms of food?

Tags: meaning

In Sling Blade (1996), in the Frank's garage, Karl opening a can of potted meat:

> Frank: You think it's really got peckers in there?
>
> Karl: You know better than to say that word.
>
> Frank: lt smells kinda funny.
>
> Karl: It's a little **loud**. Looky right here.

What does "loud" mean in terms of food?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to be sure (even within the broader context, which I found via Google), but my guess is that Karl is using an adjective for "high in intensity" usually applied to one sensory modality -- auditory -- to refer to stimulus from another modality -- olfactory.

In other words, by applying "loud" to food, Karl really means that it has a "strong", or "pungent" smell.